# Trying to get FocuesApp on a Mac

Tags: objective-c, error-code

i am trying to build a programm that outputs me actuall selected Application.
But for some reason i get the AXError:-25204 .
According to the reference this error implies that the app i am trying to meassage is ether busy or not responsive. I dont understand why...

I am working guided from this tutorial: http://cocoatutorial.grapewave.com/2010/01/retrieving-the-window-that-has-focus/

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/NSAccessibility.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

if(!AXAPIEnabled()){
    NSLog(@"AXAPI not Enabled");
    return 0;
}

AXUIElementRef _systemWideElement;
AXUIElementRef _focusedApp;
CFTypeRef _focusedWindow;
CFTypeRef _position;
CFTypeRef _size;
AXError e;


//Get the window that has the focus
//Get the app that has the focus
_systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide();
NSLog(@"%d",_systemWideElement);
e=AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(_systemWideElement,
                              (CFStringRef)kAXFocusedApplicationAttribute,
                              (CFTypeRef*)&_focusedApp);
NSLog(@"%d,%d",kAXErrorSuccess,e);

e=AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue((AXUIElementRef)_focusedApp,(CFStringRef)NSAccessibilityFocusedWindowAttribute,(CFTypeRef*)&_focusedWindow);
if( e == kAXErrorSuccess) {
    NSLog(@"App ausgewaehlt");

    if(CFGetTypeID(_focusedWindow) == AXUIElementGetTypeID()) {
        //Get the Window's Current Position
        if(AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue((AXUIElementRef)_focusedWindow,
                                         (CFStringRef)NSAccessibilityPositionAttribute,
                                         (CFTypeRef*)&_position) != kAXErrorSuccess) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Retrieve Window Position");
        }
        //Get the Window's Current Size
        if(AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue((AXUIElementRef)_focusedWindow,
                                         (CFStringRef)NSAccessibilitySizeAttribute,
                                         (CFTypeRef*)&_size) != kAXErrorSuccess) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Retrieve Window Size");
        }
    }
    //NSLog(@"%@",_size);

}else {
    NSLog(@"%d",e);
}
[pool drain];
return 0;
```

}

Somebody has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `NSAccessibility` API stuff I believe you want to be using `kAXFocusedWindowAttribute` and probably `kAXSizeAttribute` which are documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityCarbonRef/Reference/reference.html). From my experience you don't want to mix the 2 APIs and you want to use the C APIs to access other application's elements.